# Can we place `<img>` inside `<h1>` according to web standards?

Tags: w3c, web-standards, xhtml-1.0-strict, xhtml

Can we place `<img>` inside `<h1>` according to web standards? like this

```
<h1> Demo text <img src="anyimage.jpg"/> </h1>
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Yes, you can - the [DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html) says:

```
<!ELEMENT h1  %Inline;>
<!ENTITY % Inline "(#PCDATA | %inline; | %misc.inline;)*">
<!ENTITY % inline "a | %special; | %fontstyle; | %phrase; | %inline.forms;">
<!ENTITY % special "%special.pre; | object | img ">
```

That basically means `h1` can contain `%Inline`, which is made of various things, including `img`

Answer (score 52):

Look who is using it: http://www.w3.org/

```
<h1 class="logo"><a tabindex="2" accesskey="1" href="/"><img src="/2008/site/images/logo-w3c-mobile-lg" width="90" height="53" alt="W3C" /></a> <span class="alt-logo">W3C</span></h1>
```

Comment: Well, that might be wrong usage. When using screen reader it reads out loud: "W3C W3C". Because it reads out loud alt attribute and span element. I'm not sure but if span were defined with display: hidden it wouldn't read it. [Good reading for ALT text is here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/alt.html).

Comment: I agree, responding to this late. But if it were 2018. I would set the alt equal to the empty string, " ". And keep the span with a screen-reader the only css.

Comment: @Gcamara14 You mean something like <h1><img src="img.png" alt="" /><span class="screen-reader-text">My title</span></h1>    Do search engines dock rankings based on hidden text like that?

Answer (score 20):

Yes, this is allowed.  But don’t forget to set the `alt` attribute on the `img`!

Comment: +1 for mentioning `alt`. Basically when the image cannot be displayed, the `alt` text acts as the contents of the `h1`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no.

You can place an image inside an h1 element, but not quite like that … the [alt](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html) attribute is mandatory.

Answer (score 4):

To summarize the other answers, **it is W3C valid to use an `<img>` inside an `<h1>`.**

Though to be completly valid you should add an `alt` attribute to your image, because it's mandatory. This attribute doesn't need to contain text. It's better letting it empty than repeating what is already written in the `h1` tag.

In your case if the image is purely decorative it should be:

```html
<h1>Demo text <img src="anyimage.jpg" alt=""/></h1>
```

More info on text alternatives for decorative images: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/decorative/

If the image has a particular meaning or contains a text different than the one in the h1, then use an appropriate alternative.