# Is having an <img> tag inside an <h1> valid html?

Tags: html, standards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we place `<img>` inside `<h1>` according to web standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605454/can-we-place-img-inside-h1-according-to-web-standards)

I would like to add a small image to appear at the end of every H1 header, the easiest way would be to create the image and simply

```
<h1>Title <img src="image.png" ></h1>
```

I do not want to use a background image because I want the image to be positioned at the end of the h1 title, which means that it will vary and a background can only be fixed.

Is having an img tag within a header tag invalid code in any html standards?

I ran this through W3 markup validation with HTML5:

```
<h1>Hello <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"></h1>
```

and I get the following error:

Line 1, Column 19: Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.

Anyone know what that means?

Comment: You need to supply a complete html document to the validator. Starting with doctype, html, head (including title) and then your h1 and img tags inside the body.

Answer (score 3):

let your page validate from w3c, they will tell you. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Good idea but I am doing it locally on a wordpress theme! Do you know of anywhere you can type code in and see if it's valid?

Comment: Use the tab **Validate by Direct Input**

Comment: I didn't know that could be done! Thanks! I ran the test and it sends errors :o

Answer (score 3):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) the content of an `<h1>` tag should be "phrasing content", which includes `<img>` tags as well.

On the other hand you could use the [CSS-style `background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-position) to align the background image like you want:

```
background-image: url( image.png );
background-position: right;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is invalid but as suggested by @Ekonion w3.org is a correct option to check it.

Apart from this, you can also use css `background-position` to position your image in the background as per your requirement. Just an alternate anyway :)

Hope it helps.