# HTML Image tag does not work regardless of what I do

Tags: html, image

I have spent a lot of time researching this issue and I am not sure I understand why this happens. I have changed the directories for my image, changed what my image is called, where the image is placed etc. I feel like there may be something I am missing. I want to keep the image within the header tag.

```
<h2><img src="Pictures/Rest.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="400" height="400" alt="Restaurant"/></h2>
```

Comment: The header is one thing, the header tag is another.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am still green when it comes to coding.

Comment: I don't see any problems with this. It seems to work fine: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFBG7D0C07P6

When placing an image within a <h2> tag, you must have alt text and you do.

Check your css for the img-thumbnail class and h2 tag

Comment: Thank you, Saeed. Does the source have to be a website? It always seems to work with a website but not when I have the images on my laptop. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728850/how-to-give-src-to-the-img-tag-in-html-from-the-system-drive) SO question to use an image from your had drive.

Comment: Thank you, Jeroen. I found an answer that suggested I move the images to the same folder as the index.html folder. I am going to try that next!

Answer (score 0):

yes it possible use it with anchor tag.

more detail  check it this link    [Can we place `<img>` inside `<h1>` according to web standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605454/can-we-place-img-inside-h1-according-to-web-standards)